# contructor with array and for loop showing an error

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows

```
// Our Person constructor
function Person (name, age) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
}
// Now we can make an array of people
var family= new Array();
family[0]= new Person("alice", 40);
family[1]= new Person("bob", 42);
family[2]= new Person("michelle", 8);
family[3]= new Person("timmy", 6);

// loop through our new array
for(var i = 0; i <= family.length; i++) {
console.log("My name is " + family[i].name);
}
```

Don,t no why but it is showing an error shown below

```
My name is alice
My name is bob
My name is michelle
My name is timmy

---
We're running a test below to make sure your code works.
My name is aliceMy name is bobMy name is michelleMy name is timmy
TypeError: family[i] is undefined
```

i am not able to correct this. kindlly fix it for me.

Comment: Loop should end at `i<family.length`

Comment: Arrays are 0-based. First index = 0, last index = (length - 1)

Comment: its fixed , Thanks @Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i <= family.length
```

Should be

```
i < family.length
```

Because, array indeces starts from zero. Hence when you reach to the max value for `i`, there is no element present in the array hence the `undefined`

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: @Rajesh Isn;t this solve the problem ? Short answer doesn't mean `comment`

Comment: Yes it does. But this is  a very basic problem and a comment should be more than sufficient. Also its not about length. There must be many posts with this issue but we will not be able to find as title points something else.

Comment: its fixed. Thanks alot @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: @Rajesh `Also its not about length.` Are you sure ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ i meant *length of answer* not `length` of array. :-p